# Get the dates from a specific week in a month

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I managed to create a method that returns all the dates from a specific month and year.

My code for it:

```
   public static IEnumerable<DateTime> AllDatesInMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
        for (int day = 1; day <= days; day++)
        {
            yield return new DateTime(year, month, day);
        }
    }
```

Now what I want is to get the all dates from s*pecific week number of a month*

**Example:** I want to get the dates from the *2nd week* of `December` and the starting day is `Saturday`.

The result would be:

```
12/8/2018 Saturday
12/9/2018 Sunday
12/10/2018 Monday 
12/11/2018 Tuesday
12/12/2018 Wednesday
12/13/2018 Thursday
12/14/2018 Friday
```

Comment: Actually, `8th Dec 2018` is **Saturday**, could you, please, check the example? What is the desired output for the `1st` and `2nd` weeks? What if I want `5th` week? What if week starts from `Monday`?

Comment: So, the week starts on Sunday - what if the month starts on Monday? does the first Sunday of the month always counts as the first week, or in this case, does it count as the second week? What if the month ends in Tuesday? Do you want to get the rest of the week even if it belongs to another month?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I fixed it, I am sorry I didn't check it carefully.
1st week would be from Dec 1 to 7,
If you want to display the 5th week. It would display 3 dates only which is 29,30,31 . 

If the week starts from Monday, It will always get the FIRST SATURDAY of the Month

Answer (score 4):

The only difficulty is to compute the *starting date*; let's use *modulo arithmetics* for this:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> AllDatesInWeekOfMonth(int year, int month, int week) {
  DateTime start = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

  start = start
    .AddDays((CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek - start.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7)
    .AddDays(week * 7 - 7);

  for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    if (start.Month == month) {
      yield return start;

      start = start.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
// Different cultures have different first day of week
// In case of Invariant Culture week starts from Sunday
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

string test = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    AllDatesInWeekOfMonth(2018, 12, 2)
       .Select(date => date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy (dddd)")));

Console.WriteLine(test);
```

**Outcome:**

```
09 December 2018 (Sunday)      // <- Week starts from Sunday
10 December 2018 (Monday)
11 December 2018 (Tuesday)
12 December 2018 (Wednesday)
13 December 2018 (Thursday)
14 December 2018 (Friday)
15 December 2018 (Saturday)
```

Comment: @Mary Jhealyn Villena: you are welcome! Next time, please, start from elaborated examples.